# kineticjs - how to add more than one stage

Tags: kineticjs

I’m trying to build a pdf annotator (using pdf.js to render pdf , kineticjs to draw, and pdfsharp as a server side library). On button click a stage is being added on the top of my pdf. The problem starts when pdf has more than one page. In this case I need to add separated stage to each page. Any ideas how can that be achieved?

Comment: In KineticJS, each layer is a new Canvas

Comment: ^ Actually Ani, each layer is **2** new canvases! :P

Comment: @projeqht Yh, I know one is a buffer though and that's why I said only 1 for all practical purpose of any application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to loop through pages in my pdf and add stage to each one with different container name. So that was simple. The problem I'm having now is to give them dynamic names (stage1, stage2....) In code below I'm adding stage (which is global var) to each page. So basically, however silly that may sound, I'm looking for a way to create some global vars which will represent new stage object for each page.

```
for (var i = 1; i < PDFView.pages.length; i++)
    {
        var kineticContainer = 'container' + i;
        var pageContainer = "#pageContainer" + i;
        var container = $('<div  id="' + kineticContainer + '"  class = "sym_container"   >' + '</div>')
                                                 .css("left", 0).css("top", 0)
            stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: kineticContainer,
            width: Sym_CanvasSize * Sym_Ratio,
            height: 800,
            id: kineticContainer
        });
        layer = new Kinetic.Layer();            

    }
```